# Python JSON TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, json

I am currently trying to parse some data from a get request response and I keep getting this error: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

it would be great, if anybody could help me out what i am trying to solve. thank you so much in advance.

```
import requests
import json


class userList(APIView):
    def get(self,request,format=None):

        user_data = []
        url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1'

        try:
            r = requests.get(url).json()
            user = {
                'id': r['data']['id'],
                'email': r['data']['email']
            }
            user_data.append(user)
            return Response({"user_data":user_data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

```
{
data:{

0:{
'id'    : 1
'email' :   "george.bluth@reqres.in"
'first_name' :  "George"
'last_name' :   "Bluth"
'avatar' :  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"
}

1:{
'id'    : 2
'email' :   "apdas@reqres.in"
'first_name' :  "apdas"
'last_name' :   "loanz"
'avatar' :  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"
}

2:{
'id'    : 3
'email' :   "joan@reqres.in"
'first_name' :  "joan"
'last_name' :   "homli"
'avatar' :  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"
}
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please post a traceback?

Comment: Is data a dictionary of a list? Separate each `x[y]` into it's own line so you can see which is causing the error, i suspect you need `r[0]['data']['id']`

Comment: What line is flagged in the traceback. (You should include the traceback in your question.)

Comment: Inspect `r['data']` and check if it has a `list` instead of a `dict`. In a quick look here at your json content I think that the correct is use `r['data'][someIndex]['id']` for example.

You should be use something like `r['data'][0]['id']`

Comment: i am getting one value. Instead of adding [0], is it possible that iterate through results in case there is more than one result. @GeekSilva

Comment: `for user in r['data']` and then you could access the user data as `user['id']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
user_data = [{'id': x['id'], 'email': x['email']} for x in r['data']]
```

**Output:**

```
[{'id': 1, 'email': 'george.bluth@reqres.in'}, {'id': 2, 'email': 'apdas@reqres.in'}, {'id': 3, 'email': 'joan@reqres.in'}]
```

Comment: TypeError:  list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Comment: here , for x in r['data']

Comment: i didn't get what you mean

Comment: @xxnora the json you posted is not same as json you are getting from the url